# Своя функция сортировки чисел по возрастанию

Tags: php

Сделал функцию, которая сортирует числа по возрастанию,
только она получилась костыльная.

Я не знаю, что сделать с элементом, который оказался самым маленьким 
и я ему присвоил новое значение, потом после всей сортировки, удалил его.

Если бы я удалил элемент, который нашёлся, то есть самое меньшее число, то массив укоротился бы и тогда условие while, больше не сработало.

```
$massiv = [3,2,5,1,7,4,6,8,9,10,13,11,14,12, -1,0];

    function minSort($arr, $newArr = []) {
        $length = count($arr) - 1;

        while(count($newArr)-1 < $length) {

            for($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
                if($arr[$i] == min($arr)) {
                    $newArr[] = $arr[$i];
                    $arr[$i] = 99999999999; 
                }
            }
        }

        while($newArr[count($newArr) - 1] == 99999999999) {
            unset($newArr[count($newArr) - 1]);
        }

        return $newArr;
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(minSort($massiv));
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: есть достаточно большое множество различных алгоритмов сортировки. вы хотите изобрести что-то свое? Тогда расскажите нам словами, как вы хотите это сделать. А лучше начните изучать различные алгоритмы,  например, с самого простого - с сортировки методом пузырька. А что бы понять что делать с каким элементом, возьмите и нарисуйте весь ваш процесс сортировки на листе бумаги.

Comment: если вы тут хотите по порядку искать минимальные элементы, и складывать их в новый массив то так и сделайте. Пока исходный массив не пуст, изначально предположите что первый (нулевой) элемент массива минимальный. Пройдитесь по массиву и сравните этот минимум с остальными значениями. Найдете меньше - запомните позицию. После того как прошлись по массиву - запихайте минимум в новый массив, и удалите его из исходного. Вы я так понимаю, что то похожее пытаетесь сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас и циклов многовато... Вот вариант по проще [*если понадобится сортировка по убыванию, то вместо min() напишите max()*]:

```
function mySort($arr, $newArr = []) {
    while (!empty($arr)) {
        if (($k = array_search(min($arr), $arr)) !== false) {            
            $newArr[] = $arr[$k];
            unset($arr[$k]);
        }
    }

    return $newArr;
}

$a = [3,2,5,1,7,4,6,8,9,10,13,11,14,12, -1,0];

echo '<pre>'; print_r(mySort($a)); echo '</pre>';
/*
Array
(
    [0] => -1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 6
    [8] => 7
    [9] => 8
    [10] => 9
    [11] => 10
    [12] => 11
    [13] => 12
    [14] => 13
    [15] => 14
)
*/
```